# Why I'm getting this message: "Interface cannot be used (error 229)"

Tags: usb, error, console

I've plugged an USB NFC/RFID reader, model ACR112U-A9 provided by ACS Ltd.

Although it is plugged I can't read anything and I keep getting this logs in console:

```
09/06/15 14:13:00,901 com.apple.SecurityServer[83]: reader ACS ACR122U PICC Interface: state changed 16 -> 34
09/06/15 14:13:00,902 com.apple.SecurityServer[83]: token in reader ACS ACR122U PICC Interface cannot be used (error 229)
09/06/15 14:13:01,249 com.apple.SecurityServer[83]: reader ACS ACR122U PICC Interface: state changed 32 -> 18
```

How can I solve this issue? Do you know what is the `error 229` and why it's triggered?

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  Are you able to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. But you can up vote this question to increase its visibility. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: hey, guys, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Solved, check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: You need to download the ACS ACR122U Drivers for Mac OS X 10.x.

Here the [download page](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/driver/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/) and the direct link for [PC/SC Driver Installer 1.1.0 (Mac 10.5, Mac 10.6, Mac 10.7, Mac 10.8, Mac 10.9, Mac 10.10) (2014-09-17 306KB)](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-driver-unified/5133/ACS-Unified-INST-MacOSX-110-P.zip).

You have to install it even if the installer is not properly signed.

It will install the useful driver in: `/usr/libexec/SmartCardServices/drivers/ifd-acsccid.bundle`

Now you are able to use the card reader.
If you want to test it out, I made a simple [project here](https://github.com/goodotcom/rfid-reader-http).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above answer is that it doesn't work with Mac OS X 10.11.x, as SIP (System Integrity Protection) mechanism blocks any attempts to write to system directories such as /usr/libexec/...

I found that the workaround proposed by Metsma here [Re: el capitan 10.11.4 unable to see smartcard](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/43807?answerId=139013022#139013022) solved the problem of "interface or token cannot be used (error 229)" on 10.11.5. Also, once the right symlink was placed - I did not need to install any additional driver. The existing libccid.dylib.1.14.21 proved sufficient.